# Evaluation of variable

Tags: c++, variables, evaluation

What does evaluation of variable mean?

```
int main(){
   int variable;
   variable;
}
```

What does "variable" do? Why evaluation of "variable" should produce its own value?

Comment: What specific meaning are you looking for here? `variable;` is an *expression* which gets evaluated, though in this case the resulting value is discarded. An optimizer will likely strip out that code because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You might mean `int x = 1;` and then `int y = x + x;` which *evaluates* to `2` at the point of definition. If later you say `x = 3` then `y` does not magically become `6`, it remains `2`.

Comment: @tadman I'm looking for the explanation of what does evaluating of expression mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if there can be an answer to this that you find acceptable. If you look up ["evaluate" in a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evaluate), you might find it defined as "to determine the value of". So evaluating `variable` should produce its own value by definition, no? What other outcome are you expecting?

Comment: In this specific case, I believe the code has undefined behavior because `variable` is uninitialized. (Quietly doing nothing is one possible consequence of undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "evaluate an expression" means to compute its result and execute its side effects.

Expression `variable` has no side effects. (Unlike something like `x = 1` or `printf("abc")`).

It's result has type `int` (determining the type is not a part of the evaluation, because it never requires runtime computations), and the result has some arbitrary value (actually reading the value would cause undefined behavior, since the variable is uninitialized). This result also has an address, which is the address of `variable` (you can apply `&` to this expression and get that address).

In short, `variable;` doesn't do anything.

---

> [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)
>
> Evaluation of each expression includes:
>
> - *value computations*: calculation of the value that is returned by the expression. This may involve determination of the identity of the object (glvalue evaluation, e.g. if the expression returns a reference to some object) or reading the value previously assigned to an object (prvalue evaluation, e.g. if the expression returns a number, or some other value)
> - Initiation of *side effects*: access (read or write) to an object designated by a volatile glvalue, modification (writing) to an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations.

Comment: What if there will be literal instead of `int variable; variable;`?
And what if this variable would have user defined type? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Vanconts What do you want to know about those cases? An expression consisting of a single literal doesn't have side effects. It'd have some value like any other expression, but no address because it's not an lvalue (unless it's a string literal). An expression consisting of a single variable name of any type never has side effects, and is always an lvalue.

Comment: I want to know what would be a "produced value" in expression of single literal? As you said that result of computation of "variable" is some int, ok , but what is the result of computation of literals? same about user defined types @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Vanconts For an `int` literal like `42` the result also has type `int` (with the value `42`), but since the expression `42` is not an lvalue (it's prvalue), the result of this expression doesn't have an address. User-defined types are not really different from built-in types in those cases.

Comment: But if expression like `variable;` doesn't do anything, why do people say that it produces a value if it doesn't? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Vanconts `;` is not a part of the expression. *"why do people say..."* I suggest to not dig deep into the formalities of the language. Answering those questions without messing up the precise terms is getting tricky... I'll try. (The result of) the expression `variable` refers to the variable `variable`. It doesn't "produce" a value, as in no action is performed. It *has* a value, which is the value of variable `variable`, which you can *read* (e.g. by doing `int x = variable;`; the formal term for "reading a value" is *rvalue-to-lvalue* conversion).

Comment: "Expression variable has no side effects."  In _this_ case, because of how the variable is declared (in automatic memory), evaluating "variable" has no side-effects.   However, I have seen this evaluation technique used in an embedded system to read a memory mapped hw 'register', and thus cause some state change in the equipment being controlled.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating basically means "executing the code".

In an expression, `variable` "loads" an `int` containing the value of that variable into the CPU.

Evaluating the statement `variable;` "loads" that value to the CPU, which then does nothing with it.  (The compiler is smart enough to detect that nothing happens, and will just ignore this. If you're lucky, it'll also produce a warning letting you know that this does nothing and that's suspicious.)

Evaluating the statement `int a = variable;` "loads" that value to the CPU, and then assigns it to a new local named `a`.

Comment: so sentence "evaluation of "variable" produces its value" means loading value of variable(in my case value of its int type) to processor memory?

Comment: @Vanconts C++ is not that specific about what happens. Evaluating an expression produces its value, but _where the produced value exists in hardware_ is not important to C++.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm just trying to understand what do you mean "produces its value"?

Comment: @Vanconts For example, the expression `1 + 2` produces 3. The produced value can be discarded, however -- which is what happens in your example code. The expression `variable` produces whatever value is held in the named variable.

Comment: @Vanconts: Yes: you can treat it like "evaluation of a variable loads it into processor memory".  The C++ standard says when the compiler sees `int a = variable;`, it must produce whatever code it needs to result in the same result. The compiler _is_ allowed to cheat in any and every way as long as the result is indistinguishable from the code, which is why cdhowie is being vague about details.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, as with other languages, *expressions* are *evaluated*, typically to return a singular value. This happens by following the [operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to apply operators in the correct order.<sup>1</sup>

In the simplest case:

```
int x = 2;
int y = x + x * x;
```

Where the *right-hand-side* (relative to the `=` assignment operator) of the expression requires evaluation in each case. In the first statement it's easy, it's just `2`. In the second the evaluation order rules apply and you get `2 + 4` or `6`.

Evaluation is the process of applying *every* operator in the correct order which will yield a singular value, the result of that expression.

Think about evaluation as similar to how you might when determining the result of a mathematical formula. Different rules apply, but the principles are the same.

---

<sup>1</sup> The order arguments are evaluated may not necessarily be the order in which they're defined.

Comment: Excuse my nitpicking, but `=` is not an operator in this case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What's a better term in this case? [This definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) seems to apply.

Comment: I don't know the proper term for it, so "the `=` symbol` or just "the `=`".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's an operator of some kind. Presumably it has a name other than its symbol. Maybe the "assignment operator"?

Comment: @tadman but what does evaluation mean for single operand of expression? In most cases in binary code it will not produce any values .

Comment: Every expression "produces" a value. Can you think of an expression that doesn't?

Comment: @tadman An operator must be a part of an expression, that's what I mean. Grammatically `=` is not a part of one, in this case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It can be part of an expression, like `if ((x = y) > z)` but yeah.

Comment: @tadman I understand that all expressions must produce a value. If I got it clearly single literal expression produces its value , for example : 
`7;`
so this literal will produce its value, but what kind of value?It must produce 7 , but what is 7? Is it int or what? What does it mean to produce the value?

Comment: "This happens by following the operator precedence rules so that the operations happen in the correct order." operator precedence does not directly define operations evaluation order, please correct your statement, it is too confusing.

Comment: Numbers are `int` by default. This is why when specifying numbers that are out of `int` range you must append `L` or `LL` for `long` and `long long` respectively, or for floats `f`, and such.

Comment: @Slava Added some caveats. The simple version is often "wrong" because it glosses over some more esoteric ramifications.

Comment: @tadman so if I declare the literal 
`int main()
{
7;
}`
This literal has type int?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat C++ allows you to define your own assignment method on a class by defining `operator=`, so obviously the standards committee considers `=` to be an operator.

Comment: I am not sure that made it better, novice programmers way too often confused with this assuming that higher precedence operations would evaluate first, which is not the case.Unfortunately your answer would add to that confusion.

Comment: Would it be better to say the operators are "applied" in the correct order even if they are evaluated in an arbitrary order? This is a deep rabbit hole to fall down on something that is just scratching the surface of what an expression is.

Comment: @MarkRansom My point was, whether or not `=` is an operator depends on where it appears. If you do `int x; x = 42;`, then it's an operator, because it's inside of an expression. If you do `void() = delete;` then it's not an operator, because there's no expressions here, and same for `int x = 42;`. Nitpicking, as I said.